# Testing Geometric mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, geometric-mean

we know that t-test consider the arithmetic mean only. How could I compare the geometric means of two different groups or several groups?

Comment: Under what distributional assumptions?  Or are you seeking some kind of asymptotic result? Or perhaps a nonparametric test? (out of interest, though it may also be relevant to an answer, given a hypothesis test is a test of population coefficients, presumably you mean to ask about comparing population geometric means ... in which case what does the population geometric mean tell you?)

Comment: One way is to test arithmetic mean of the logarithms of the data.

Comment: By which way we can do it ?